# How much hosting RAM does a webRTC app require?

Tags: node.js, deployment, socket.io, hosting, webrtc

I will be hosting a webrtc application. All the server needs to do is just pass around messages like room number, ice candidates, disconnects, etc, just all those messages for signalling. I am using socket.io and node.js.

The server pretty much just passes text around. There is no sign ups, no database, it's all in memory. It keeps track of a list of users that are online (just how many are online), and list of rooms that are taken. 
So a few lists of numbers, and it passes text between users so that they can connect via webrtc.

Now, obviously when (if) I get a huge amount of traffic coming in, the lists might get kind of big, like maybe 10k-20k 5 digit numbers in each list (there are only a couple big lists).

And all that passing around, like the disconnect and connect. I need a server that can do this stuff fast, perferably a free server. I mean, it's only text, so it shouldn't be that big of a deal, right? But my app is structured around connecting a person to the next person who connects. So, if a whole bunch of people connect at around the same second, then I need a quick hosting server that can handle that to the milisecond... Will this even be a problem?

What exactly should I be looking for in a server, if I'm just using memory for number lists (no databases), and passing around text stuff.

Comment: You might want to prefer a cloud solution so you can upscale if needed. In general I wouldn't be worried. This doesn't really sound like a problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this doesn't have anything to do with `webrtc` itself. What you basically want is a `chat-server`, a server that sends data from one `client` to the other.
Second, the type of `server` is irrelevant to the amount of `RAM` required to run it. What matters is how much `clients` you will have concurrently. (to some extent, `game servers` will obviously consume more `RAM` even without `clients`).
Third, more `RAM` does NOT mean faster handling. That is, if you don't fully use the available `RAM`, adding more won't do you any good. Obviously, when you exceed the available `RAM` things start to slow down a lot. [Read more about it here](https://superuser.com/questions/786683/are-computers-with-more-ram-potentially-faster-if-not-all-memory-is-usually-in-u)

Now, with those out of the way, let's see what you need. You can make a very rough estimation by connecting a few `clients` to a `server` and see how much `RAM` it uses. Check if the amount of `RAM` goes up if these `clients` start calling each other and by how much it goes up. You now have a minimum and a maximum amount of `RAM` for x `clients`. I would do this test with about 10 `clients`.

Now that you can make an estimation, calculate how much the minimum and maximum `RAM` is for your expected userbase. It will become more and more a preference thing from here on out, but I would at least double that amount and then round up to the nearest amount of `RAM` that "makes sense" (14.7GB becomes 16GB, 28.32GB becomes 32GB etc...)

I will add, from my own experience with `webrtc` with about 1000-1500 concurrent users that 8GB is easily enough. But it's really up to the amount of users you expect.

On a side node, I very much recommend [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/) for a server. It's super easy to use, any programmer that knows `javascript` (so basically any programmer) can create a `chat-server` in `nodejs` in a day or two. Take a look at [this open-source webrtc server in nodejs](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc/tree/master/server_example)

Comment: I have written a server in node.js, but I am just curious as to how to deploy it on the web.